# How to create variables with incremental names

Tags: javascript, variables

I have some probles to understand how to do this

I have a variable created to hold an object:

```
var myobject = new object();
```

everything is fine; the name is 'my object' and the content is a new object.

If I want 10 variables, I need to type 10 variable names.

```
var myobject1 = new object();
var myobject2 = new object();
var myobject3 = new object();
var myobject4 = new object();
.... and so on
```

now; I would like to increment the name of the variable (not the content), with a counter, so it doesn't matter how many times I need a new object; the name will just change in incremental way (I can't reuse the same name for the variable, it is a long story). So the result will be the same as above, but without me actually writing 10 times (on n times) the variable name.

In sh, I can refer to either `myobject` for the name, or `$myobject` for the content of that variable; but JS doesn't seems to have this approach.

I tried to put down the logic, but I can't see how you actually increment the variable name:

```
//global variables
var counter=0;
var tempname;

function makeplentyofobj(){

    if (temp name)
        tempname= new object(); //this should make myobjectN
    else
        myobject= new object(); //this makes myobject1
    counter ++;
    tempname ='myobject'+counter; //this make a name for the next object)
}
```

When I run this, the compiler will put in myobject, the new object (counter goes to 1, temp name contains the string 'myobject1').

if I call the function 2 times, the second time I will have counter=1, and tempname will contain the string 'myobject1'. which is what I want to use as name of the next variable . Since tempname is not empty, I branch in the else condition, but the CONTENT of tempname will be changed from string to object.

Instead, I want to obtain a new variable name, which increment with the counter, so every time that I call `var my object = new object();` as the counter increment, I get

```
myobject1=new object();
myobject2= new object();
....
```

How can I obtain this in JS?

EDIT:

Thanks for the reply; it is a duplicate; altho my question took quite a while to go trough a reasoning of what I did, while the other is a plain "how do I do that".

It took efforts to do mine; I guess next time I will just skip the effort :)

Comment: Why not use an array?

Comment: Do *not* use this approach. Use a *container* object: either an array with indices, or a normal object with appropriate keys.

Comment: I think you need to read about arrays

Comment: That is what arrays are for.

Comment: @newbiez - Don't sweat that it was marked a duplicate as long as you got the answer you wanted.  You should search first to try to find a previous question, but if it doesn't come to you so you post a question and someone else knows of a duplicate - that's all fine.  There's no problem with that.  You asked a question and got an answer that solved your issue which is what this is all about.

Comment: Indeed; thanks a lot for your help. I did a search, but I am new with the language; the only similar request to create incremental variables was closed as non constructive. I didn't think about search for "declare variable programmatically" :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual solution to this kind of problem is to put your objects in an array.  That simplifies both storing them and retrieving them.

```
var objArray = [];
objArray.push(new object());
objArray.push(new object());
objArray.push(new object());
objArray.push(new object());
```

Or, you can even put them in the initial declaration:

```
var objArray = [new object(), new object(), new object(), new object()];
```

If you really just want generic objects, it can be as simple as this:

```
var objArray = [{}, {}, {}, {}, {}];
```

---

Then, referencing a given element is as simple as

```
var obj = objArray[n];
```

Keep in mind that arrays start with index `0` as in `objArray[0]`.

Comment: `objArray.push({})` though it's `object()` not `Object()`...

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 - They aren't creating a generic objects here - that would have a capital letter `Object`.  I assume they're just using pseudocode here.

Comment: var objarray=[]; objarray[counter].push(new object(); would work too?

Comment: @jfriend00 - Yea I noticed that.

Comment: Yes, just using pseudocode jfriend00; thanks

Comment: @newbiez - If you are using `[counter]` then don't use `.push`. Choose either one.

Comment: @jfriend00 this has been closed as a duplicate, can you please remove the answer to keep things nice and clean?

Comment: @JK. - Please read: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132600/should-i-delete-my-answer-to-a-question-thats-marked-as-a-duplicate

Comment: @JK - Valid answers already posted do not need to be deleted just because someone else found a relevant duplicate.